# How does this PHP filter use ZIP codes?

Tags: php, html, arrays, json

This site (https://www.helpendhunger.org/find-food-assistance/) has an input for zip search, and one would assume it returns locations based on corresponding zip codes. But I don't think that's the case.

Looking at the code below, the filter looks like it uses associated latitude and longitude values to determine the results. Still, the zip code must be coming into play somewhere, but I can't figure out how. Can anybody help me understand what's going on here?

Here's the main portion I'm concerned with, followed by the full code.

```
<?php 
    case 'zip':
        $none = !empty($_REQUEST["none"]) ? $_REQUEST['none'] : 'false';
        $lat = $_REQUEST["lat"];
        $lng = $_REQUEST["lng"];
        $x = 0;
        unset($loc_array);
        $loc_array = array();
        foreach ($locations as $loc) {
            $radius = 35;
            $zip_location = $loc['zip_code'];
            $lat_loc = $loc['latitude'];
            $lng_loc = $loc['longitude'];
            $distance = distance($lat, $lng, $lat_loc, $lng_loc, "M");
            if ($distance == $radius) {
                array_push($loc_array, $loc);
            }
        } 
        $count = count($loc_array);
        if ($count > 0 && $none == 'false') {  ?>
            <div class="table">
            <?php foreach ($loc_array as $location) {
                include ('../lib/locations.php');
            } ?>
            <script> var _jsonNew = <?php echo json_encode($loc_array) ?>; </script>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="no_results">
                <div class="in">
                    <div class="response">There were no results for this zip code, please try again.<br><span>or</span></div>
                    <div class="button" data-county="all">View All Locations</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script> var _jsonNew = <?php echo json_encode($locations) ?>; </script>
        <?php } ?>
```

Full code:

```
<?php 
require("../wp-load.php");
global $wpdb;
$oper = !empty($_REQUEST["oper"]) ? $_REQUEST["oper"] : die("No Oper");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM locations ORDER BY ID DESC";
$locations = $wpdb->get_results($sql,ARRAY_A);

function sortLocs($a, $b) {
    return ($a["location_title"] > $b["location_title"]) ? 1 : -1;
}

usort($locations, "sortLocs");

if (!function_exists("stripslashes_deep")) {
    function stripslashes_deep($value)
    {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value);
        } else {
            $value = trim($value);
            $value = stripslashes($value);
        }
        return $value;
    }
    
}

$locations = stripslashes_deep($locations);

switch($oper){
    case 'county':
        $county_request = !empty($_REQUEST["county"]) ? $_REQUEST["county"] : die("No County");
        $county = strtolower($county_request);
        $x = 0;
        unset($loc_array);
        $loc_array = array();
        foreach ($locations as $loc) {
            $county_location = strtolower($loc['county']);
            if ($county_location == $county) {
                array_push($loc_array,$loc);
            }
            if ($county=='all') {
                array_push($loc_array,$loc);
            }
        } 
        $count = count($loc_array); ?>
        <div class="table">
        <?php 
        foreach($loc_array as $location) {
            include ('../lib/locations.php');
        }
        ?>
        <script>
            var _jsonNew = <?php echo json_encode($loc_array) ?>;
        </script>
        <?php
    break;
    case 'zip':
        $none = !empty($_REQUEST["none"]) ? $_REQUEST['none'] : 'false';
        $lat = $_REQUEST["lat"];
        $lng = $_REQUEST["lng"];
        $x = 0;
        unset($loc_array);
        $loc_array = array();
        foreach ($locations as $loc) {
            $radius = 35;
            $zip_location = $loc['zip_code'];
            $lat_loc = $loc['latitude'];
            $lng_loc = $loc['longitude'];
            $distance = distance($lat, $lng, $lat_loc, $lng_loc, "M");
            if ($distance == $radius) {
                array_push($loc_array, $loc);
            }
        } 
        $count = count($loc_array);
        if ($count > 0 && $none == 'false') {  ?>
            <div class="table">
            <?php foreach ($loc_array as $location) {
                include ('../lib/locations.php');
            } ?>
            <script> var _jsonNew = <?php echo json_encode($loc_array) ?>; </script>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="no_results">
                <div class="in">
                    <div class="response">There were no results for this zip code, please try again.<br><span>or</span></div>
                    <div class="button" data-county="all">View All Locations</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script> var _jsonNew = <?php echo json_encode($locations) ?>; </script>
        <?php } ?>
    
    <?php break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell, but it seems as if there's something that's converting the zip code to a lat/lng (easily done with Google Maps in JS), and must be doing a center-of-poly search to the lat/lng of the locations they're supporting.